# Using method reference instead of multi argument lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm confused about concept behind "Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type". Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) has an example about this:

```
String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John", "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Most of the examples I have seen for this kind of method reference is like this: If lambda is like: `x -> x.func()` then you can write it like `ClassOfX::func`. The example in documentation says:

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference
>   String::compareToIgnoreCase would have the formal parameter list
>   (String a, String b), where a and b are arbitrary names used to better
>   describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method
>   a.compareToIgnoreCase(b).

The question is: for any two argument lambda like `(a, b) -> a.func(b)` the `func` method must be instance method of first argument and second argument of lambda will be passed as an argument to that method? If we have multiple argument lambda then `func` method must be instance method of first argument of lambda and other arguments of lambda will be passed to `func` in the order the appear in lambda? I mean instead of `(a, b, c) -> a.func(b, c)` we can write `ClassOfA::func`

I'm sorry for my English. I hope I made the problem clear.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`SomeClass::func` can mean two things, depending on whether `func` is a static method or an instance method.

(1) If `func` is a static method, then `SomeClass::func` is a lambda that just passes all the arguments to the method:

```
(a, b, c) -> SomeClass.func(a, b, c);
```

(2) If `func` is an instance method, then `SomeClass::func` is a lambda that uses the first argument as the instance, as you thought:

```
(a, b, c) -> a.func(b, c);
```

where `a` has type `SomeClass`.

**EDIT:** Sotirios' answer demonstrates yet a different type of method reference: `example::method` where `example` is a reference variable (instead of a class name).  This means the same as

```
(a, b) -> example.method(a, b);
```

or perhaps more accurately

```
(a, b) -> __someFinalTemporary.method(a, b);
```

where `__someFinalTemporary` is assigned to `example` at the point where the method reference is evaluated, so that if `example` changes later, the method is still called using the earlier value of `example`.

[The fourth kind is `SomeClass::new` which passes the arguments to a constructor.  I think that's all of them.]

Answer (score 13):

Here's a small example demonstrating the behavior of an instance method reference.

```
public class Example {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Example example = new Example();
        Functional methodRef = example::method;
        methodRef.funct("a string", strings);
        System.out.println("List now contains: " + strings);

        Functional lambda = (String s, List<String> l) -> {
            example.method(s, l);
        };
        lambda.funct("another string", strings);
        System.out.println("List now contains: " + strings);
    }

    interface Functional {
        void funct(String value, List<String> list);
    }

    void method(String value, List<String> toAddTo) {
        System.out.println("adding");
        toAddTo.add(value);
    }
}
```

It prints

```
adding
List now contains: [a string]
adding
List now contains: [a string, another string]
```

The two are more or less equivalent. In the lambda's case, the variable the method is invoked on needs to be effectively `final`.

Comment: It looks a little bit like magic. why does `Functional methodRef = example::method;` work if Example does not implement Functional? It does work, I just don't really understand how.

Comment: @PauloGuedes The method reference it's is transformed into something that that implements `Functional`. In this case, the two arguments to `func` would be propagated to `method`, invoked on example`.

Answer (score 7):

> I mean instead of (a, b, c) -> a.func(b, c) we can write ClassOfA::func

Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

According to Joshua Bloch in his "Effective Java" (3rd Edition), there are 5 types of use cases for method reference.

[image]