# how to express "(String a)-> a.contains("o")" using java 8 method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

the "String::contains" is wrong. but how to express the lambda?

In addition , when I write this in IntelliJ IDEA :

> obj.testPredicate(list, String::contains);

I get the error in "String::contains" : Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context. but the contains is not static method. I am confused by the tips.

my code as follows:

```
public <T> List<T> testPredicate(List<T> list , Predicate<T> predicate){
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(T t: list){
        if(predicate.test(t)){
            result.add(t);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and this is the caller:

```
@Test
public void testPredicate() throws Exception {
    List<String> listTemp = lambda.testPredicate(list, s -> s.contains("o"));
    System.out.println(listTemp);
}
```

**why the simplest lambda cannot be replace by method reference?**

and I see the [Using method reference instead of multi argument lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139725/using-method-reference-instead-of-multi-argument-lambda).

it says

> (2) If func is an instance method, then SomeClass::func is a lambda that uses the first argument as the instance, as you thought:
>   (a, b, c) -> a.func(b, c);

there is no defference with my (String a, String b)-> a.contains(b); why method reference did not work?

Comment: In this case, you really can't.

Comment: What's the signature of `obj.testPredicate`?

Comment: `public static boolean containsO(String s) { return s.contains("o"); }` Then when you need it: `obj.testPredicate(list, MyClass::containsO)`.

Comment: Don't put a link to your code: put your code directly here! Just copy/paste it.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I paste my code.

Comment: *there is no defference with my (String a, String b)-> a.contains(b);*. But that's not what you have at all. Your lambda has one parameter; this has two!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own predicates:

```
public class StringPredicates {
  public static Predicate<String> contains(String contained) {
    return s -> s.contains(contained);
  }
}
```

Then you can use them similarly to this:

```
obj.testPredicate(list, StringPredicates.contains("o"));
```

Note, that you don't need method references to use such a construct. As I always say: use the right tool when needed! In this case you have a variable, so it's not advisable to use a method reference.

If you really must use a method reference, you can always write this:

```
public static boolean containsO(String s) {
  return s.contains("o");
}
```

And then use it:

```
obj.testPredicate(list, StringPredicates::containsO);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you cannot express it with method reference. It would work if you would like to use current element of iteration as a parameter to another function. Take a look at following example:

```
final String str = "o";

final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet");
list.stream()
        .filter(it -> it.contains(str)) // (1)
        .filter(it -> str.contains(it)) // (2)
        .filter(str::contains)  // (3)
        .findFirst();
```

In this case `(2)` and `(3)` are equal and `(1)` expresses completely different expression that cannot be represented by a single method reference. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

String `contains` method requires one parameter that is "o" in this case.

While filtering on list of string's when we are specifying predicate usual
sytax is a -> a.contains("o").

IntelliJ gives suggestion only when method don't have parameter to method.

e.g. when you are specifying predicate like this:

```
a -> a.isEmpty()
```

Then alternative syntax is `String::isEmpty` which is more readable than the previous one.

But in case of predicate where you need to call method with one or more parameter you don't have alternative way to specify other than this: 
`a -> a.contains`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in your Test class that returns the predicate

```
public class Test
{
    ..
    public static Predicate<String> contains_o()
    {
        return s -> s.contains("o");
    }
```

Then use it when testing the predicate

```
    @Test
    public void testPredicate() throws Exception
    {
        List<String> listTemp = lambda.testPredicate(list, Test.contains_o());
        System.out.println(listTemp);
    }
    ..
}
```

Comment: @Lino: I suppose, because `Test::contains_o()` isn’t valid Java syntax and there is no way to fix that other than removing the method reference as a method reference to a method which already returns a `Predicate` makes no sense in this context. So in the end, this is a non-working piece of code still containing the lambda expression `s -> s.contains("o")` and not providing any answer to the OP’s question, how to replace that with a method reference.

Answer (score 0):

Static re-usable Predicate

```
    public static Predicate<String> contains(String contained) {
        return s -> s.contains(contained);
    }
```

Test code

```
@Test
    public <T> List<T> testPredicate(List<T> list , Predicate<T> contains){
    return list.stream()
        .filter(contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using

```
listTemp.stream().filter('o'::contains)
```

and then terminating this stream as you need.